# How do I find same element in an array and sum of their values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array :

```
var type = ["Petrol", "Petrol", "Transport", "Petrol", "Transport", "Personal"];
var price = [100,250,50,25,10,20];
```

Basically `type[0]` and `price[0]` is type and its price. `Petrol = $ 100`. Same with the others according to their array index.

I wanted to find duplicate element in array `type` and add their `price` then display to the log.

Example :

`type[0]` and `type[3]` is the duplicate element which is `Petrol`. So I want to add their values `price[0]` + `[price[3]` as long there is same element.

- Log 1 : price[0] + price[3] = display total of Petrol
- Log 2 :
  price[2] + price[4] = display total of Transport

I made some progress in here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AziziMusa/orb8q1yq/2/). But it only work with 2 same element, more than that, it won't work and it little mess too.

Comment: What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/orb8q1yq/5/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this.

```
<span id="op"></span>
var type = ["Petrol", "Petrol", "Transport", "Petrol", "Transport", "Personal"];
var price = [100,250,50,25,10,20];
var str='';

for(var i=0;i<type.length;i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<type.length; j++){
        if(type[j]==type[i]){
            price[i] += price[j];
            price.splice(j,1);
            type.splice(j,1);
        }
    }
}

$.each(type, function(i){
    str += type[i]+':'+price[i]+'  ';
});

$('#op').text(str);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whe2f4uj/1/

Answer (score 3):

This looks less messy IMO

```
var result = {};
type.forEach(function(name, i) {
    result[name] = (result[name] || 0) + price[i]
});

console.log(result) // { Petrol: 375, Transport: 60, Personal: 20 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use an object for this? Use the `type` array as keys, and add the values of `price` to each key:
Seeing as, in your fiddle, you're keeping track of the running total, I've added that here, too:

```
var total = 0,
    typePrice = {};//creates object
for (var i=0;i<types.length;++i)
{
    if (!typePrice.hasOwnProperty(types[i]))
    {//type not set on object
        typePrice[types[i]] = 0;//set to 0
    }
    typePrice[types[i]] += price[i];
    total += price[i];
}
console.log(typePrice);
//then to list:
var elem = document.querySelector('#foo');
for (var p in typePrice)
{
    if (typePrice.hasOwnProperty(p))
        elem.innerHTML += p + ': ' + typePrice[p] + '<br>';
}
```

That's all there is too it.

## [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkp80450/)

Comment: +1 , didn't realize someone posted the same while I was writing mine. No need for my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

What about using object properties ?

```
var type = ["Petrol", "Petrol", "Transport", "Petrol", "Transport", "Personal"];
var price = [100,250,50,25,10,20];

var result = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < type.length ; i++) {
    var t = type[i];
    if(result[t]) {
        result[t] += price[i];
    } else {
        result[t] = price[i];
    }
}

/*
    result = {
        Petrol   : 375,
        Transport:  60,
        Personal :  20
    }
*/
```